# How to a drop table without classes and mappings?

Tags: nhibernate

I'm using ASP.NET's [SimpleMembership](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx) which uses my User table that I'm creating via Nhibernate. SimpleMembership automatically creates Membership and Roles tables (without Nhibernate) which has a foreign key with the User table (ie: Membership and Roles has a foreign key that belongs to my User table). I do not have classes or mappings for these *Membership* and *Roles* tables.

In my nunit test project, I'm creating these tables in my setup but **I'm having trouble dropping all the tables in my tear down with the following implementation.**

> var se = new SchemaExport(_configuration); se.Drop(true, true);

The Drop() fails to drop the User table because the Membership and Roles tables depend on the User table. I'm pretty sure I have to delete this Membership and Roles table before trying to remove the User table. **How do I manually delete the *Membership* and *Roles* table without creating classes and mappings for them?**

Comment: write raw sql and delete them..

Answer (score 0):

i would personally just remove all data with `session.Delete("from Object");` but you can add additional tables to drop in the config:

```
config.CreateMappings(Dialect.GetDialect(config.Properties))
    .AddTable(catalog, schema, tablename, null, false, "drop");
```

maybe the tables have to be added first before all other mappings

Comment: What is the differene between `catalog` and `schema` in this function? Aren't those synonyms in this case? I mean, I connect to a MySql database (for instance) and choose a `Initial Catalog`, or a `Database`, in the connection string. And MySql Workbench uses the term `Schema` as in 'Set as Default Schema' functionality. I can't find any documentation on this `CreateMappings().AddTable` function.

Comment: .AddTable is not the usual public API. NH has a lot of extensibility points but many are not well documented.

Comment: It appears that the first parameter (at least for MySql) can be ingored, that is, the catalog can be left null. As the string "catalog.schema.tablename" is created. So if you do not wish to define a catalog, just put `null` there. It worked for me.